# Is there blowfish for python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, blowfish

I need to decrypt a file I had encypted and forgotten about, and I encrypted with blowfish. I remember the key but I don't remember how I encrypted. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cryptography 3.3.2 includes Blowfish and works with python 2.7

https://cryptography.io/en/3.3.2/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption.html#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.algorithms.Blowfish